# exceptions handling with XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, exception

hello I not really sure what is the right way to handle exceptions with elements i create.

when I try to enter wrong code i do see a message box:

[image]

but i want to use newApartment.StreetName and print a message says 
" newApartment.StreetName not exist "

```
try
{
    if ((File.Exists("Apartments.xml")))
    {
        XDocument apartmentXml = XDocument.Load("Apartments.xml");
        var newApartment = new Apartment();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the street name:");
        newApartment.StreetName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the House Num:");
        newApartment.HouseNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var apartmentExist =
            from apartment1 in apartmentXml.Root.Elements("Apartment")
            where ((string) apartment1.Attribute("street_name") == newApartment.StreetName) &&
                  ((int) apartment1.Element("Huose_Num") == newApartment.HouseNum)
            select apartment1;

        var apartment = apartmentExist.FirstOrDefault();

        if (apartmentExist.Any() == false)
        {
            throw new CustomException(apartment.Value);

        }
}
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    ex.TestThrow(ex.ToString());
}
```

Custom exception class:

```
 class CustomException : Exception
    {
        public CustomException(string message)
        {

        }
        public void TestThrow(string ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex);
        }

    }
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Apartments>
  <Apartment street_name="sumsum">
    <Huose_Num>13</Huose_Num>
    <Num_Of_Rooms>4</Num_Of_Rooms>
    <Price>10000</Price>
    <Elevator>true</Elevator>
    <Floor>2</Floor>
    <parking_spot>true</parking_spot>
    <balcony>true</balcony>
    <penthouse>true</penthouse>
    <status_sale>true</status_sale>
  </Apartment>
</Apartments>
```

thx!

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception that you immediately catch?  That's bad practice.

Comment: To answer your question, you're seeing the `ToString()` representation of the error, because that's what you pass into `CustomException.TestThrow()`.  If you really want to do this, simply pass do this: `ex.TestThrow(" newApartment.StreetName not exist");`.

Comment: Tempted for -1... I don't see how your question relates to XML...

Comment: Side note. In case no apartments found you are passing to exception `apartment.Value` but if apartment not found that will throw `NullReferenceException` (apartment is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Custom Exception class you didn't define a variable to store error message. I see you have one parameter in your constructor, but you didn't set it.

```
 class CustomException : Exception
{
    public string errorMessage;

    public CustomException(string message)
    {
       errorMessage = message;
    }
    public void TestThrow(string ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex);
    }

}
```

Throw it like this, you should pass your error message to the constructor

```
 throw new CustomException(newApartment.StreetName + " not exist");
```

And call it:

```
catch (CustomException ex)
{
    ex.TestThrow(ex.errorMessage);
}
```

Also you don't need TestThrow method for this:

```
catch (CustomException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: OP did send it: `throw new CustomException(apartment.Value);`, but it will be `null` because the only way they get there in the code is if `apartment.Any() == false`.  In any event, this is **not** a good use of try catch blocks, IMO.

Comment: I throw now new CustomException(newApartment.StreetName.ToString());
and i can see the "wrong name" i entered in the Box but i not getting back to the menu i want where the try is..

Comment: lior, don't throw it like that check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Instead of throwing and catching some custom exceptions just check if apartment was found and show message:

```
var apartment = apartmentExist.FirstOrDefault();
if (apartment == null)
    MessageBox.Show("Apartment not exists");
```

Comment: `MessageBox`, not `MessageBos` :)

Comment: @Selman22 - That may be, but OP should clarify that in their question.

Comment: @Selman22 agree, question is vague, but throwing and immediately catching them is really bad idea. And why in this case marking question with linq and xml tags? I suggest to wait and see what OP will say :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yeah i agree with that